# How can I deploy my web application war, which have many dependencies in WSO2 AS 5.2.1

Tags: wso2-as

I am trying to upload my web application.war to wso2 as 5.2.1 and when I did that, it displayed in the console the following error message. How can I fix it?

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://584.fwk29855494:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/dausbel/Documentos/WSO3/wso2as-5.2.1/repository/deployment/server/webapps/news-desktop/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```